# WebSocket using VB6.0

Tags: vba, sockets, websocket, vb6

I'm using a project in VB6.0 and I need to implement WebSocket for VB6.0 but unfortunately, I could not find any resources over the internet, so please assist me on this, I've been searching Winsock to use TCP/IP socket servers, I need proper guidance on this.

I found the below code from somewhere but it seems not useful.

```
Private Sub Winsock1_ConnectionRequest(Index As Integer, ByVal requestID As Long)
    Winsock1(Index).Close
    Winsock1(Index).Accept requestID

    Dim Packet As String

    With Winsock1(Index)

        Packet = "HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake" & vbNewLine
        Packet = Packet & "Upgrade: WebSocket" & vbNewLine
        Packet = Packet & "Connection: Upgrade" & vbNewLine
        Packet = Packet & "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: s3pPLMBiTxaQ9kYGzzhZRbK+xOo=" & vbNewLine

        Data = Empty

        .SendData Packet

     End With
End Sub
```

Comment: There is a related thread here: https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?890708-vb6-Secure-Websocket

Answer (score 0):

I have developed websocket solution for vb6 but comments / varables are in Slovenian language so... fast answer:

you have to calculate key in 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept'. It changes on every connection so you cannot use fixed response...

"Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " + Key + vbCrLf + _

Comment: Please don't ask users to contact you off-site, that's not allowed. You can share your contact information on your profile page if you want.

Comment: Problem is that  project is too big to shere in code ... but yes, I understand, sorry.